# Referencing messages of other .proto files

Tags: import, protocol-buffers, relative-path, proto

I have seen there already similar problems published, I could not resolve the problem with the solutions proposed.

I am struggeling to reference a proto in another proto file.

I have the .proto file example.proto that is referencing A.proto in the dependency folder, example.proto is placed next to the dependency folder.

**A.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

package dependency;

message AttributeA {
  // Some attribute.
  string body = 1;
}
```

**example.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

import  "src/proto_test/dependency/A.proto";

package example;

message CheckRequest {
  // The request attributes.
  int32 id = 1;
  dependency.AttributeA att = 2;
}
```

The server file looks as following:

**Server**

```
const grpc = require("@grpc/grpc-js");
const PROTO_PATH = "./src/proto_test/example.proto";
var protoLoader = require("@grpc/proto-loader");

const options = {
  keepCase: true,
  longs: String,
  enums: String,
  defaults: true,
  oneofs: true,
  includeDirs: [path.join(__dirname,"/proto_test/dependency")]
};
var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, options);
const proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);

const server = new grpc.Server();

server.bindAsync(
  "127.0.0.1:50054",
  grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),
  (error, port) => {
    console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:50054");
    server.start();
  }
);
```

**Error**

```
Error: no such Type or Enum 'dependency.AttributeA' in Type .example.CheckRequest#
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Please include your `protoc` command. I suspect this is where the error's arising. You will need to `--proto_path` that includes all directory roots that allow `protoc` to find the necessary protos.

Comment: I am not using any protoc command, I just run the node.js server written above. The protos are loaded using the @grpc/grpc-protoloader library, I suppose the problem is with the **includeDirs** declaration in the options

Comment: Yes, apologies. NodeJS -- IIRC -- auto-generates for you. Yes, you will need to provide references to the root paths from where the packages may be found.

Comment: So I have added the dependency folder path in **includeDirs** (see my update above), but the problem persists...

Comment: `src/proto_test` is your `PROTO_PATH`. This is the root directory from which your proto structure hangs. For consistency, `example.proto` (should probably be called `check_request.proto`) defines itself in `package example` and it should be in a subdirectory called `example` alongside `dependency` but that doesn't matter for this example.  Now, you can reference `depdendency.AttribtueA` from `example.proto`, prefixing the `PROTO_PATH` to the package, the compiler can find `src/proto_test/dependency/AttributeA`.

Comment: Ok I thought in PROTO_PATH I need to provide an absolute path to a proto file. I have found a solution for my problem, by adding the path of the example.proto to includeDirs and changing the import in example.proto.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know exactly why, but this code is working:

**example.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";

import  "dependency/A.proto";

package example;

message CheckRequest {
  // The request attributes.
  int32 id = 1;
  dependency.AttributeA att = 2;
}
```

**Server**

```
    const grpc = require("@grpc/grpc-js");
const PROTO_PATH = "example.proto";
var protoLoader = require("@grpc/proto-loader");
var path = require('path')

const options = {
  keepCase: true,
  longs: String,
  enums: String,
  defaults: true,
  oneofs: true,
  includeDirs: [
    path.join(__dirname,"/proto_test/dependency"),
  path.join(__dirname,"/proto_test")]
};
var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, options);

console.log(packageDefinition);

const proto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);

const server = new grpc.Server();

server.bindAsync(
  "127.0.0.1:50054",
  grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),
  (error, port) => {
    console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:50054");
    server.start();
  }
);
```